# Recursively fetch JSON and draw object until 404

Tags: javascript, json, recursion

I'm currently trying to recursively call a JSON object from a URL, and then draw a line with the current object information (should build a square once complete). Once it fetches a JSON object and draws the line, it should then use the URL within the fetched object to call the new JSON object with the next details.

It should stop once the final url returns a 404, and should build an array of all the URLs used to construct the image.

The objects are structured like so:

```
{
  x1: 0,
  y1: 0,
  x2: 100,
  y2: 100,
  col: 'red',
  url: 'http://nexturl.com/nextLine.json'
}
```

I currently have this function:

```
async function linkedDrawing(canvas, url) {
    let urlArr = [url];
    const c = document.getElementById(canvas).getContext('2d');

    const response = await fetch(url);
    let json;

    while(response.ok) {
        json = await response.json();

        c.lineWidth = 3;
        c.strokeStyle = json.col;
        c.beginPath();
        c.moveTo(json.x1, json.y1);
        c.lineTo(json.x2, json.y2);
        c.stroke();

    }

    urlArr.push(url);
    return urlArr;
}
```

How can I modify this to get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

I think you were almost there. Could you try this and let me know if this works?Haven't tested this though, since that url is not accessible.

```
const c = document.getElementById(canvas).getContext('2d');
let url = 'http://someurl';

linkedDrawing(c, url, [])
    .then(console.log)
    .catch(console.log);

async function linkedDrawing(canvas, url, urlsArray) {
    urlsArray.push(url);
        const response = await fetch(url);
        if (response.ok) {
            let json = await response.json();
            c.lineWidth = 3;
            c.strokeStyle = json.col;
            c.beginPath();
            c.moveTo(json.x1, json.y1);
            c.lineTo(json.x2, json.y2);
            c.stroke();
            return await linkedDrawing(canvas, json.url, urlsArray);
        }
        else {
            return urlsArray
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Although this still doesn't seem to work for me

Comment: I had a typo. but could you tell me what error exactly you are getting in the browser?